# Scraping Data Using HTML Using VBA- Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Tags: html, vba, screen-scraping

Trying to bing something (don't judge me, Google was a little more difficult to do) and simply create a message box of the first description listed. The key, however, is that I want to directly type something into the search bar and then search it (not simply fill in a string portion of a URL). I was making decent progress, but now cannot get rid of the error (runtime error 91) "Object Variable or With Block variable not set."

Basically, I have called `getElementsByClassName` on the HTML doc of the searched results, and filled out the class that I want. I know this returns a collection of elements (as the names of the classes of the search results are mostly the same), so I index into the first class it gives me. Then I simply want to print out that HTML by MsgBoxing the innerHtml of that element. However, I end up with the same error above. I have also tried adding, after I have called on `getElementsByClassName`, a `.getElementsByTagName` instead of `.innerText` and end up with the same error. In other words, it seems like every time I use this element variable with another dot method, this error comes up. Not sure how to fix.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim element As Object
    Dim text As String


    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    my_url = "https://www.bing.com"
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate my_url

    Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
    Loop
    Wait 1

    ie.Document.getElementById("sb_form_q").Value = "123"

    ' Pressing enter
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    Set element = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("b_caption")(0)
    MsgBox (element.innerHTML)
End Sub
```

```
Sub Wait(seconds As Integer)

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:0" & CStr(seconds))

End Sub
```

I simply want a MsgBox of the caption of the first search result on bing. If someone could help, that would be awesome! Clearly I'm somewhat new at webscraping and I am hoping to use the concepts I learn on this project to update a wayy out-of-date system. Thanks!

Comment: You're not waiting for the search results to load after you submit the query...

Comment: ^^ Also, don't use sendKeys to submit.